# Use WLST to Retrieve Local Application Path

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I am currently automating a process of moving Weblogic applications from old servers to new servers. I was unable to find a way to list the local application path for a deployed Weblogic application using WLST. The closest I found was:

```
appInfo=cmo.getAppDeployments()
for app in appInfo:
    app_path = getPath(app)
    print app_path
```

which will return something like:

```
InternalAppDeployments/test.war
```

This is not the directory I am looking for. I was wondering if someone had some input on how to retrieve the local directory for deployed Weblogic applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do it with WLST:

```
ls('/AppDeployments') # this will list all of the deployments
cd('/AppDeployments/<app name>')
cmo.getAbsoluteSourcePath() # this will list the full path
```

Some things you could try instead of WLST:

Navigate to the /config/ folder and do a:

```
grep source-path config.xml
```

This will list the full path to the deployment IF that deployment was deployed with nostage staging-mode. Those paths will be relative if the deployment was deployed with stage for the staging-mode, it will be copied to each managed server that was targeted for the deployment and you will get relative paths like you mentioned above...

Those ear/war files likely live under:

```
 <domain>/servers/<server name>/stage/<deployment name>
```

Or under

```
 <domain>/sbgen
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I added in the getAbsoluteSourcePath() function and got what I needed. Thank you so much.